# How to create pointcut for an abstract method

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am trying to create a pointcut for an abstract method implemented in the child class, but the AOP never gets called.

Here is my Minimal Java Code:

```
package com.example;

public class Service {
    private ParentAbstractClass clazz;

    public Service(ParentAbstractClass clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void process() {
        clazz.method();
    }
}
```

This is the service class which has an abstraction of the Class to be injected and it calls a method.

My abstract class which has some common logic and an Implementation specific code which is an abstract method.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class ParentAbstractClass {
    public void method() {
        abstractMethod(List.of("test"));
    }

    public abstract void abstractMethod(List<String> names);
}
```

This is the class which provides an implementation for the abstract method.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

public class ConcreteClass extends ParentAbstractClass {
    @Override
    public void abstractMethod(List<String> names) {
        System.out.println("Look up! AOP should have executed");
    }
}
```

With this setup, I am using spring XML to configure my beans.

```
<bean id = "clazz" class="com.example.ConcreteClass"/>

<bean id="myservice" class="com.example.Service">
    <constructor-arg ref="clazz"/>
</bean>

<bean id = "aspect" class="com.exmple.TxAspect"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="mergeEnableAspect" ref="aspect">
        <aop:pointcut id="mergeServicePointCut"
                      expression="execution(* com.example.ConcreteClass.abstractMethod(..))"/>
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="mergeServicePointCut" method="test" arg-names="pjp"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

And finally the AOP class:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;

public class TxAspect {
    public void test(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {

        System.out.println("I am not going to do anything");

    }
}
```

In my `abstractMethod` I am doing something which is transactional in nature and I have business need of controlling the transactions manually but, My aspect class never gets invoked. Can someone please help me out to figure out what mistake I have done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by constraints of Spring AOP implementation. Here is the quote from [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop):

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, calls within
>   the target object are, by definition, not intercepted. For JDK
>   proxies, only public interface method calls on the proxy can be
>   intercepted. With CGLIB, public and protected method calls on the
>   proxy are intercepted (and even package-visible methods, if
>   necessary). However, common interactions through proxies should always
>   be designed through public signatures.
>
> Note that pointcut definitions are generally matched against any
>   intercepted method. If a pointcut is strictly meant to be public-only,
>   even in a CGLIB proxy scenario with potential non-public interactions
>   through proxies, it needs to be defined accordingly.
>
> If your interception needs include method calls or even constructors
>   within the target class, consider the use of Spring-driven native
>   AspectJ weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework. This
>   constitutes a different mode of AOP usage with different
>   characteristics, so be sure to make yourself familiar with weaving
>   before making a decision.

So you have two possible approaches to solve the problem:

1. Use your aspect only on methods which are called by other beans (no self invocation)
2. Use AspectJ AOP implementation. I prepared a simple example using AspectJ compile time weaving, the code is hosted on [github](https://github.com/yaroslavcev/spring-aspectj-compiler)

---

AspectJ approach in a nutshell:

Modify transaction aspect as follows:

```
package com.example;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class TxAspect {

    @Around("methodsToBeProfiled()")
    public void test(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("I am not going to do anything");
        pjp.proceed();
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.ConcreteClass.abstractMethod(..))")
    public void methodsToBeProfiled(){}
}
```

Reduce XML configuration as follows:

```
  <bean id="clazz" class="com.example.ConcreteClass"/>

  <bean id="myservice" class="com.example.Service">
    <constructor-arg ref="clazz"/>
  </bean>
```

Compile the application using following maven plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>${ascpectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>test-compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the reference. I will award the bounty in an hour. Please remind me if I don't :) SO has a limitation of accepting and awarding at the same time..